# Accessing PC on another subnet under a different router

Tags: networking, router, dns, subnet

My home network is setup as above diagram,
[image: network setup]

- I have an isp provided router which provides access to the internet over fiber connection.
- ISP router has an internal IP of 192.168.1.1
- I have another wifi router (tplink) that is connected to the ISP router.
- The Ip given to the personal tplinik router by the ISP router is 192.168.1.2.
- The tplink router assigned itself the IP address 192.168.0.1.
- Most of my devices are connected to the tplink router over wired or wireless connection
- Hence I have 2 subnets, 192.168.1.X and 192.168.0.X series.
- DHCP service is enabled on both routers.
- I have a pihole running in the 192.168.0.x subnet, which "could" be used for DHCP / DNS if the solution demands it.
- Recently I purchased a New PC, that PC is connected directly to the ISP router as it is physically near the isp router and I don't wish to run an additional ethernet cable to the tplink router.
- The new PC connected to the ISP router gets an IP address of 192.168.1.3, internet works fine on the new PC, but it is not reachable from the devices on the 192.168.0.X series and vice versa.
- Pings to 192.168.1.3 fails from 192.168.0.111 and vice versa

I wish for the new PC (192.168.1.3) to access the services running on 192.168.0.X subnet.

How do I fix it? Which concepts should I learn to proceed to fix this problem

Comment: `Which concepts should I learn to proceed to fix this problem` - routing - 192.168.1.1 should have a static route to 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.2

Comment: General FYI: it's never recommended to connect any client device to an ISP provided router, and instead firewall all devices behind your/a second router, as ISP's maintain remote access to their routers - rogue employee(s) can access downstream device and network data on the LAN unless explicitly firewalled from doing so behind a second router.

Comment: You are talking about YOUR idea how to solve your problem, asking us to help. But is your idea really the fitting path? — Please explain us why this way? Why a subnet? Why ... . Just tell us your aim, your priorities and essential elements of your project. // BTW: The comment of *JaromandaX* is the direct solution to this question.